# Plot columns of matrix vs same variable

Tags: plotting, matrix, list-manipulation

I have a table of dimensions {10,3} say. Each column is the value of some function f(x,a) wrt to x and the parameter $a~ ( =1,2,3$ say) refers to the columns. So for example if we let

$f(x,a) = a \sin(x)$ then the first column of my matrix contains values $$1\cdot \sin(x), (\text{where }x=1,...10)$$
second column 
$$2\cdot \sin(x)$$

and so on. Obviously one can plot column 1 vs x and so on for the other columns. But is there a simple way to plot each column vs x in one and the same graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = Table[a Sin[x], {x, 1, 10}, {a, 1, 3}]
```

`ListPlot[Transpose@data]` is what you need:

```
Show[Plot[Table[a Sin[x], {a, 1, 3}], {x, 1, 10}], 
 ListPlot[Transpose@data, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]], 
 Frame -> True, Axes -> {True, False}]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, very simple and clean!

Answer (score 0):

```
f[x_, a_] = a Sin[x];
avals = {1, 2, 3};
xvals = N@Subdivide[0, \[Pi], 9];
mat = Outer[N@*f, xvals, avals];
Dimensions@mat
(*returns {10,3}*)
```

as exampledata (please provide that next time in your question).
You can "pair" each of your columns with the corresponding xvalues by "threading" the column and the xvalues with the function `Thread`.

```
Thread[{xvals, mat[[All,1]]}]
(*returns {{0, 0.}, {\[Pi]/10, 0.309017},...}*)
```

Do this for each column separately (here we transpose the table first so our columns become rows).

```
Thread[{xvals, #}] & /@ Transpose[mat]
```

and finally, wrap a `ListLinePlot` or `ListPlot` around it

```
ListLinePlot[Thread[{xvals, #}] & /@ Transpose[mat]]
```

[image]
I hope that's what you wanted. If not, let me know.

Cheers